# Can't connect mongoDB database to Atlas due to server and shell mismatch

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, heroku, mongodb-atlas

have a Node.js app deployed on Heroku and now I am trying to connect the database. I ran all steps smoothly until the time I had to connect them through Terminal using `mongo "mongodb+srv://<app name>-da9ev.mongodb.net/test"  --username admin`. The answer I received was intriguing because it said the shell and server do not match (and they do, tested that several times) and that there was an implicit session running:

```
cassiano$ mongo "mongodb+srv://<app name>-hugcu.gcp.mongodb.net/test"  --username admin
MongoDB shell version v4.2.1
Enter password: 
connecting to: mongodb://<app name>-shard-00-00-hugcu.gcp.mongodb.net:27017,<app name>-shard-00-01-hugcu.gcp.mongodb.net:27017,<app name>-shard-00-02-hugcu.gcp.mongodb.net:27017/test?authSource=admin&compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb&replicaSet=<app name>-shard-0&ssl=true
2019-11-06T11:45:03.277+0100 I  NETWORK  [js] Starting new replica set monitor for <app name>-shard-0/<app name>-shard-00-00-hugcu.gcp.mongodb.net:27017,<app name>-shard-00-01-hugcu.gcp.mongodb.net:27017,<app name>-shard-00-02-hugcu.gcp.mongodb.net:27017
2019-11-06T11:45:03.278+0100 I  CONNPOOL [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Connecting to <app name>-shard-00-01-hugcu.gcp.mongodb.net:27017
2019-11-06T11:45:03.278+0100 I  CONNPOOL [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Connecting to <app name>-shard-00-02-hugcu.gcp.mongodb.net:27017
2019-11-06T11:45:03.278+0100 I  CONNPOOL [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Connecting to <app name>-shard-00-00-hugcu.gcp.mongodb.net:27017
2019-11-06T11:45:03.402+0100 I  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Confirmed replica set for <app name>-shard-0 is <app name>-shard-0/<app name>-shard-00-00-hugcu.gcp.mongodb.net:27017,<app name>-shard-00-01-hugcu.gcp.mongodb.net:27017,<app name>-shard-00-02-hugcu.gcp.mongodb.net:27017
Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("5987a296-2121-41ac-b671-0a57fda6da7a") }
MongoDB server version: 4.0.13
WARNING: shell and server versions do not match
MongoDB Enterprise <app name>-shard-0:PRIMARY>
```

Can someone help me to debug this? I can't say if its a version problem, some unfinished session or what. Thanks in advance for the availability

PS: [Atlas documentation link containing URI option](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/#bin.mongoimport)

Comment: It's not an error, it's just a warning. You can still use it, but be aware that some things may break. It's best if you use the same version of the shell and the server. In this case, please install 4.2.1 in your pc and the warning should go away.

Comment: @kevinadi, thanks. I have 4.2.1 installed (double checked a couple of times), but indeed it's giving me a further error message when I try to import the database: ```WARNING: ignoring unsupported URI parameter 'replicaset'```. Can u tell me what does it mean and, if possible, how to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Make sure the spelling of `replicaSet` with capital `S` is correct. If this is correct and you're still seeing errors, it's best to ask a new question with more relevant information rather than continuing this question.

Comment: Thanks again, @kevinadi, but this `replicaset` property comes only as a response when importing a specific collection following the query that Atlas provides. I try to look deeper, but it seems the `URI` option is not allowed with several of the other options like `host`, 'port`, etc (documentation linked to the bottom of the question)